# convert str 'A123456' to bytes b'\x0A\x12\x34\x56' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, python-2.x

I use python 2.7 and windows.

I want to convert string'A123456' to bytes: b'\x0A\x12\x34\x56' and then concatenate it with other bytes (b'\xBB') to b'\xbb\x0A\x12\x34\x56'.

That is, I want to obtain b'\xbb\x0A\x12\x34\x56' from string'A123456' and b'\xBB'

Comment: Have you read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814483/changing-string-to-byte-type-in-python-2-7)?

Comment: Strings in Python 2 are dumb bytes. They're not unicode or anything, just dumb bytes.

Comment: @Samantha Miller  I have read, but I want to  convert 'A123456' to  b'\x0A\x12\x34\x56'.

Comment: @ Alexander Huszagh  I know , but I want to convert 'A123456' to b'\x0A\x12\x34\x56'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too hard to do with `binascii.unhexlify`, the only problem you've got is that you want to zero pad your string when it's not an even number of nibbles (`unhexlify` won't accept a length 7 string).

So first off, it's probably best to make a quick utility function that does that, because doing it efficiently isn't super obvious, and you want a self-documenting name:

```
def zeropad_even(s):
    # Adding one, then stripping low bit leaves even values unchanged, and rounds
    # up odd values to next even value
    return s.zfill(len(s) + 1 & ~1)
```

Now all you have to do is use that to fix up your string before unhexlifying it:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify(zeropad_even('A123456'))
'\n\x124V'
>>> _ == b'\x0A\x12\x34\x56'
True
```

I included that last test just to show that you got the expected result; the `repr` of `str` tries to use printable ASCII or short escapes where available, so only the `\x12` actually ends up in the `repr`; `\x0A'` becomes `\n`, `\x34` is `4` and `\x56` is `V`, but those are all equivalent ways to spell the same bytes.

Comment: Nice， that fix the converting part， but how to concatenate it with other bytes (b'\xBB') to b'\xbb\x0A\x12\x34\x56'？

Comment: @liyuting: `b'\xBB' + unhexlify(zeropad_even('A123456'))`? That's just simple concatenation, and didn't seem difficult once the conversion process works.