# Python TEXT to HEX Byte String

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex

So, I've been for hours searching for this conversion without success.

I need to convert some string with Python to HEX to send to a LED Controller.

So my purpose is to convert "Hello" into HEX String and then into a Byte String to send this directly to the controller via socket.

```
>>> "hello".encode("hex")
'68656c6c6f'
```

And then convert that string into something like:

```
string = b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
```

Any advise on how to do this conversion? If I just:

```
'68656c6c6f'.decode("hex")
```

Then throws out the same "hello" instead of the bytestring.

Comment: If you need a bytearray – *not* a 'string' – then use: `bytearray('68656c6c6f'.decode("hex"))`

Comment: @usr2564301 Thats just also returning the same "hello", just like "string".decode("hex") does.

Comment: Perhaps you want to specify your Python version, as some of the syntax and results changed between 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: [Changing string to byte type in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10814483/2564301) suggests that is not possible ... Why is it important to have a 'byte string' instead of a regular string?

Comment: @usr2564301 Nervemind. Just using normal strings instead of bytestring is also working... Thanks for the guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing string to byte type in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814483/changing-string-to-byte-type-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @usr2564301 there is no direct bytestring conversion in python 2.7 as bytestrings are just "strings". Using simple hex strings also works with the LED Controller, so no need to use bytestrings.

But the question remains open as this is not a solution... at least for python 2.7.