# It used to be legal to add a string and a bytes together in Python. In which version was that changed?

Tags: python

Some time ago we used to be able to do this:

```
>>> bytes('yyy')
'yyy'
>>> 'xxx' + bytes('yyy')
'xxxyyy'
>>>
```

Now it is not allowed any more:

```
bytes('xxxx', encoding = 'utf-8')
Out[23]: b'xxxx'

'xxx'
Out[24]: 'xxx'


'xxx' + bytes('xxxx', encoding = 'utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-2c2ef4241ad7>", line 1, in <module>
    'xxx' + bytes('xxxx', encoding = 'utf-8')

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Which version of Python was it that disallowed this way of adding string and bytes together?

Comment: ...Python 3.0? [_"As the str and bytes types cannot be mixed, you must always explicitly convert between them."_](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

Comment: One of the major reasons Python 3 exists as a backwards-incompatible version of Python is to do away with this madness. In Python 2, , `bytes` was just an alias for `str`

Comment: It's an odd question.  In Python 2, all strings were byte strings, unless you specifically used `u'Unicode'`.  The `bytes` type/converter was not introduced to Python 2 until the decision was made to make all strings Unicode in Python 3.  In Python 2, it does nothing.  `bytes(xxx)` is the same as `xxx` for any string.  In Python 3, you have never been able to mix Unicode strings and byte strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing string to byte type in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814483/changing-string-to-byte-type-in-python-2-7). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814498/6340496).

Answer (score 3):

As one comment pointed out this took place in Python 3.0. The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) state:

> The type used to hold text is `str`, the type used to hold data is
> `bytes`. The biggest difference with the 2.x situation is that any
> attempt to mix text and data in Python 3.0 raises `TypeError`, whereas
> if you were to mix Unicode and 8-bit strings in Python 2.x, it would
> work if the 8-bit string happened to contain only 7-bit (ASCII) bytes,
> but you would get `UnicodeDecodeError` if it contained non-ASCII values.
> This value-specific behavior has caused numerous sad faces over the
> years.

As you can see the behaviour of this operation before Python 3.0 was dependent on the actual value of the byte data... which is pretty dangerous.